# How do I present modal view as form sheet directly without any animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

How do I present modal view as form sheet directly without any animation?
When I present the modal view, if it's portrait, it always come down from upper left corner, and if it is in landscape, it always come out as portrait and rotate to landscape mode(it takes about 0.2 second, quick but not pretty).

Anybody knows what is this problem?  It bothers me.  (I try it in a new project, it works fine, it came out directly(not from left upper corner, without rotation in landscape mode)

Help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = nil;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am currently using this,:  CustomV *v = self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"; [self presentViewController:v1 animated:NO completion:^{}] ;

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your code calling the modal view? I assume you have already added the animated tag

... presentModalViewController: YOURCONTROLLER animated: NO];

Comment: CustomV *v = self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1";       [self presentViewController:v1 animated:NO completion:^{}] ;
if I set animated to YES, it will rotate twice in the landscape mode(first portrait than rotate to landscape, and again turned to portrait very quick and then turned to landscape in about 0.2 second).  It doesn't happen in my new project, I think there is some setting is wrong?

Comment: Are the orientation settings for the two projects the same? The reason I ask is because of your point that a new project doesn't do it -- so it must be a project setting or you are making some small coding difference. I would suspect that it is not an animation you are seeing, but rather the view rotating to the correct orientation.